# Change image in xaml based on a value from another xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a Views/Doc.xaml with:

```
<navigation:Page ....
 <data:DataGrid>
  <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource TextHeaderStyle}" >
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
    <Grid x:Name="gridDocumentColumns">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hlEmail" Grid.Column="1" Tag="{Binding Index}" Click="hlEmail_Click" >
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Tag="ToolTipEmail" Opened="toolTip_ActionOpened" />
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <Image Source="../images/close.png" Stretch="None" />
        </HyperlinkButton>
    </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</data:DataGrid>
..............
```

I have a second class Views/Controls/ReadDocs.xaml (). If a certain condition in ReadDocs.xaml Code Behind is true i want to change the image source in Views/Doc.xaml to ../images/open.png

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a converter and pass a flag value to it.
This converter will returns a specific path depending upon the value you have passed.

Kindly refer the below converter for reference...

```
public sealed class ImagetoPathConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return value = "ms-appx:///Assets/Images/bk/1.png";
            }
            else if (value.ToString() == "1")
            {
                return value = "ms-appx:///Assets/Images/bk/2.png";
            }
            else if (value.ToString() == "2")
            {
                return value = "ms-appx:///Assets/Images/bk/3.png";
            }
                    }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Bind the converter in Source and pass your conditional value.

Comment: But the Source is in one File and condition in a second File. How can a pass the value from File1 to File2 and change the Image in File2

Comment: Use a static variable if you want to have the flag in code itself .. or update it in database and read the same before showing the image....